# Does this property of projection on metric space hold or not?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, convex-analysis, projection, metric-geometry

Let $(\mathcal{X}, d)$ be a complete metric space.
For any subset set $C$ of $\mathcal{X}$, we say that $C$ is convex if for any two points $x, y, \in C$, there is a geodesic $\gamma (t)$ from $x$ to $y$, such that $\gamma (0) = x$, $\gamma (1) = y$ and $\gamma ([0, 1]) \subseteq C$.
We further define the projection operator in $\mathcal{X}$ as $P(x) := \arg\min_{y \in C} d(x, y)$.

The definition of the geodesic is provided as follows (c.f. [a course in metric geometry](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.368.3775&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

> Let $X$ be a length space. A curve $\gamma \colon I \to X$ is called a geodesic if for every $t \in I$ there exists an interval $J$ containing a neighborhood of $t$ in I such that $\gamma \mid J$ is a shortest path. In other words, a geodesic is a curve which is locally a distance minimizer (i.e., a shortest path).

We also assume that the minimum in the projection operator can be achieved and the minimizer is unique. For example, if $\mathcal{X}$ is a uniformly convex space, then the minimum exists.

My question is that,
For all $z \in C$, does the inequality $d(z, P(x)) \leq d(z, x)$ hold or not?

Comment: (1).  I cannot understand what $\arg \min$ means in the def'n of $P(x).$...(2). Even if $C$ is closed (& non-empty) it may be that $\{d(x,y): y\in C\}$ has no minimum.

Comment: What is a geodesic on a metric space? They are usually defined for Riemannian manifolds. And even there your $P(x)$ may not be uniquely defined, if at all. Take as $C$ a small disk surrounding the North pole on the $2$-sphere, and as $x$ the South pole.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet My bad. Here we assume that the minimizer can be achieved. For example, if $\mathcal{X}$ is a uniformly convex space, then the minimizer exists.

Comment: @Conifold Geodesic can be defined in a length space. One can refer to [``a course in metric geometry"](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-33) for a detailed definition, and I have included it in my question. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I haven't seen this geodesic definition of convexity before, but it seems off to me. It looks like this definition would allow anything closed and path-connected to be convex (there is a geodesic between any two points in a path-connected set; the difference for convex sets is that the minimal geodesic happens to be a straight line), which is definitely false. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Zim Thanks for the comment. It should be noted that the geodesic is defined on the space $\mathcal{X}$. Please refer to ``a course in metric geometry'' [Definition 3.6.5] for the definition of convex, and the link has been provided in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be the disjoint union of the unit interval $[0,1]$ (with usual metric), and a point $x$, where $d(x,t)=\frac {4+t}6$ for $t\in [0,1]$.  As $|\frac{d}{dt}\frac {4+t}6|\leq 1$ and $\frac {4+t}6>\frac12$, we know $\mathcal{X}$ is a metric space.  It is clearly complete, as $[0,1]$ is.

We have $[0,1]$ a convex subset, and $P(x)=0$.  However $$d(0,1)=1>\frac56=d(x,1).$$

Comment: It's a nice example, thanks.